# [Vue warn]: Property "$pinia" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, integration-testing, vue-test-utils, pinia

**Context**

- We are using Vue3 and Pinia and vitest
- Rather than creating strict "unit" component tests, we're trying to do more E2E/integration testing (ie. where we're mounting and testing a component that then embeds other components and not mocking or stubbing them).

**Issue**

- Since upgrading to Vue3, we seem to get this warning whenever a "child" component also uses the pinia store. The "child" components are using the same store as the "parent".

  - `[Vue warn]: Property "$pinia" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.`

How do I make this warning go away? Is it a problem?

**What I've looked into**

- I've checked that the child components can access the test pinia store correctly, and they can (ie. my tests can validate stuff about how the child has got things from the store).  But the warning is noisy.
- I can't see anything on the pinia docs that talk about how to manage this, and
- I am not seeing other questions about this particular warning
- On the Pinia website it says:
  `When it comes to Pinia, you don't need to change anything for E2E tests, that's the whole point of these tests! You could maybe test HTTP requests, but that's way beyond the scope of this guide .`
- I've looked into @vue/test-utils [mocking and stubbing](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/stubs-shallow-mount.html#Stubs-and-Shallow-Mount), but seeing as 'mount' is the bit that connects pinia to the app, I don't know if I can pass 'mounted' child components in the `stubs` section

---

This is an example of how I am mounting my components when I try to test them:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'

wrapper = mount(FilterDrawer, {
  plugins: [
    createTestingPinia({
       stubActions: false,
       initialState: {
         search: StateFactory.build()  // because store is named 'search'
        }
     })
  ]
})
```

FilterDrawer component uses `mapStores` to use the search store. It also has child components that use `mapStores` to use the search store.

Comment: Have you properly initialized `pinia` in your `main.js` file? You need to `const pinia = createPinia(); app.use(pinia);`

Comment: "we're mounting and testing a component" - this is integration test. As for e2e, you're supposed to have the same setup as you would for regular app, so you wouldn't have problems with setting up vue plugins, this is what the docs refer to

Comment: Thanks @Wesley, yes I am.

Oh, that's interesting @EstusFlask, by the "same setup", do you mean for an E2E test I wouldn't use the `createTestingPinia` function at all,  but would just bootstrap live pinia within a vitest test file (and then not be able to mock or stub or verify calls or anything)?

Comment: @EstusFlask, given it says "you don't need to change anything for E2E tests", that does sound to me like E2E tests should look very similar to unit tests (rather than they should look completely different and not use the testing framework).

Comment: @IsabelAnastasiadis E2e/integration are sometimes mixed and used as umbrella term, but e2e primarily means testing the whole thing, i.e. the app. You're using barebone vitest that isn't suitable for real e2e because it's not a real browser. For your case (integration) you need to explicitly make sure that you either provided vue plugins and other deps the comp relies on, or mock them, depending on the case. This is what the docs show https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html#Unit-testing-components . You pasted it the wrong way and omitted "global" in mount(), probably the problem here

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask, still not convinced the difference between E2E and integration is significant in this case.

But you're right, I got the syntax wrong and should have added plugins in the `global` property, and that fixes my issue, no more warning. Thanks!  If you want to post that as an answer, I can accept it :D

Comment: Glad it solved the problem. E2E test that doesn't use vue test utils would use regular way to create app instance and would normally instantiate Pinia, probably the same main.js as in production. This is what another answer shows https://stackoverflow.com/a/77870642/3731501 . I consider this the reason why it wasn't explained further in Pinia docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html#Unit-testing-components), `mount` accepts Vue plugins in `global` property, it should be:

```
wrapper = mount(FilterDrawer, {
  global: {
    plugins: [
      createTestingPinia({...})
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a pinia instance (the root store) and pass it to the app as a plugin:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import App from './App.vue';

const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(pinia);

app.mount('#app');
```

Read the documentation [here](https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html).

Comment: Thanks Mohesn.  Yes I am doing that in my main.js file when the app is bootstrapped in code, and the app works fine normally.

My tests are "component" tests, but I am also doing a similar thing as per the testing docs on pinia.  I'll add an example to the main question so it's easier to read.